# Stuff disappears from and moves around on website when refreshed

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem on one of the pages on my website as when I refresh it some stuff completely disappears and some stuff moves around.

This is what it is supposed to look like and does when first loaded.

[image: 1]

And this is what it looks like when I refresh the page.

[image: 2]

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['usrName'])){
        header('location:login.php');
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

    <!-- Appears in the title bar in web browser -->
    <title>JWT Haulage Group Drivers Area</title>

    <meta name="description" content="JWT Haulage Group Ltd is a virtual trucking company for Euro Truck Simulator 2, UK and 
    German Truck Simulator. We have over 600 drivers registered already.">                            <!-- Meta Stuff Required -->

    <meta name="keywords" content="JWT, JWT Haulage, JWT Haulage Group, JWT Haulage Ltd, Euro Truck Simulator 2, ETS2, 
    UK Truck Simulator, UKTS, German Truck Simulator, GTS, Virtual Trucking Company, VTC">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />                             <!-- Meta Stuff Required -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />                                       <!-- CSS -->

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>               <!-- JQuery -->

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-37114333-2']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();

    </script>

    <script>
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1
    var day = currentTime.getDate()
    var year = currentTime.getFullYear()
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <div class='header'>

        <img src="./images/JWT%20Logo.png" alt="JWT Haulage Group Ltd" width="360" height="86"/>

        <h2>Drivers Area</h2>

        <div class='header-links'>

            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/JWT-Haulage-Group-Ltd-In-Partnership-With-Schumacher-Logisitics-Services/166705200103425?fref=ts" title="Like us on Facebook"><img src='http://n.vdsh.net/hosting/resources/gosocial/png/32/facebook.png' alt="Facebook Page"/></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.jwt-group.co.uk" title="Share me on Google+"><img src='http://n.vdsh.net/hosting/resources/gosocial/png/32/google.png' alt="Google+ Icon"/></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/share?url=http://www.jwt-group.co.uk&amp;text=@JWTHaulageltd%20Been%20driving%20around%20europe%20for%20JWT%20Haulage.%20Come%20and%20join%20me%20at%20www.jwt-group.co.uk" title="Tweet about me"><img src='http://n.vdsh.net/hosting/resources/gosocial/png/32/twitter.png' alt="Twitter Icon"/></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.jwthaulageltd.freeforums.org" title="JWT Haulage Forum"><img src='http://n.vdsh.net/hosting/Dan/JWT/images/JWT%20Forums%20Logo.png' alt="JWT Haulage Forum"/></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.jwthaulagegroupts2.freeforums.org" title="JWT Haulage ETS2 Forum"><img src='http://n.vdsh.net/hosting/Dan/JWT/images/JWT%20ETS2%20Forums%20Logo.png' alt="JWT Haulage ETS2 Forum"/></a>
            <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/groups/JWTHaulageLtd/" title="Join our driver group on facebook"><img src='http://n.vdsh.net/hosting/Dan/JWT/images/facebook_group.png' alt="Facebook Driver Group"/></a>

        </div>

        <ul class='drivers-navigationbar'>

            <li><a href="drivers-index.php" class='pageinactive' >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="drivers-tracker.php" class='pageinactive'>Tracker</a></li>
            <li><a href="drivers-spot.php" class='pageinactive'>Spots</a></li>
            <li><a href="drivers-log.php" class='pageactive'>Logs</a></li>
            <li><a href="drivers-account.php" class='pageinactive'>Account</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php" class='pageinactive'>Logout</a></li>

        </ul>

    </div>

    <div class='container'>

        <div class='content'>



            <div class='inthreetrucksimbar-apply'>

            <div class='inthreetrucksimbaruk'>

                <img src="./images/JWT%20UKTS-GTS%20Logo.jpg" alt="JWT Haulage Group Ltd UKTS/GTS" width="259" height="95"/>

            </div>

            <div class='inthreetrucksimbareuro2'>

                <img src="./images/JWT%20International%20Logo.png" alt="JWT Haulage Group Ltd ETS2" width="360" height="86"/>

            </div>

            </div>

            <div class='jwtinternational-application'>

                <h4>JWT Log Form</h4>

                <h4>WARNING: do not use the below form as it is currently being worked on</h4>

                The following form can be used to log your loads for JWT in ETS2.<br><br>

                <form name="jwtinternational-application-form" class='jwtinternational-application-form' action="apply-send.php" 
                method="post">

                    <div class='jwtinternational-application-left'>

                        <input type="text" class="text-box" name="forum-name" placeholder="Registered Forum Name"/><br>

                        <input type="text" class="text-box" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name"/><br>

                        <input type="text" class="text-box" name="surname" placeholder="Surname"/><br>

                    </div>

                    <div class='clear'>
                    </div>

                    <input id="submit" type ="submit" value= "Submit"/>

                </form>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class='clear'>
        </div>

        <div class='footer'>

            <div class='footer-text1'>

                <h5>

                    <script>
                        document.write(day + "/" + month + "/" + year)
                    </script>

                </h5>

            </div>

            <div class='footer-text2'>

                <h5>Copyright &copy; <script>document.write(year)</script> JWT Haulage Group VTC. All rights reserved.</h5>

            </div>

            <div class='clear'>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any code at all? Oh, wait, I forgot that we're psychics, not programmers.

Comment: Are you running any `$_SESSION` data before your `<!doctype>` or anything else that could push that down?

Comment: I didnt know what code you guys would want so if you tell me what you want ill give it to you and yes i am to check if the user is logged in but that runs on all the pages not just this one.

Comment: Maybe the html/php/css of the part you have problem with or the whole thing best?

Comment: code for that page added

Comment: Why are there no ; in the second script anyway? Just askin..

Comment: If you are on about for the date then i just never added them but it works fine without them

Comment: I'm not sure of the problem, but to be honest, if you don't follow standards, you leave self exposed to these types issues.

Comment: The problem is that when i refresh the page the navigationbar dissapears and the fb etc icons move and do do the two JWT logos but this only happens on one other page the rest are all fine.

Comment: It seems to work OK for me on the major browsers, by the way your test account credentials arn't very secure.

Comment: What when you refresh it it doesnt go like the pic? And lol its only for testing but i guess i better change it.

Comment: Hey Guys I tried it at home on my comp and it didnt happen it was all fine when refreshed so i guess it was something to do with the comp i was using.